# explicitly call netrw function in binding

Tags: key-bindings, netrw

I'm trying to bind the key `^` so that it runs `^` in normal mode by default, but calls the function bound to `-` in netrw. `-` is bound to `NetrwBrowseUpDir` in `netrw.vim`, [definition here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/7f51bbe0d19f1f0cb0321326f45a17b4f5155f89/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim#L5126) .

Here's my first attempt to bind `^` to `-`

```
nnoremap <expr>  ^  &ft ==? "netrw" ? "-" : "^"
```

This snippet will correctly detect whether the current buffer is a netrw view or not, but calls the ordinary `-` command, which moves to the first non-whitespace character of the previous line.

How do I call the plugin's function directly? In the definition I linked it's script-local, so I'm not sure how get a reference to it.

The motivation for this is that I use `-` and `=` to scroll pagewise, and so I need to shift around the default netrw bindings so they don't conflict.

```
nnoremap - <c-d> 
nnoremap = <c-u>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hacky way to get a scripts `<SID>` and use it in mappings, but I always forget it.

One way to do it would be with`:nmap`, but this probably only works if you don’t already have a mapping for `-`:

```
nmap <expr> ^ &ft ==# 'netrw' ? '-' : '^'
```

I’ve looked at the docs and do not see a configuration variable for netrw’s mappings.

However, Matt mentions a `<Plug>` mapping in the comments, so:

```
nmap <expr> ^ &ft ==# 'netrw' ? "\<Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir" : '^'
```

Comment: Netrw exports `<plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir` which seems the most suitable for this case.

Comment: on Vim 8.0,  I can confirm that `nmap <expr> ^ &ft ==# 'netrw' ? '-' : '^'` successfully remaps `^` to go up a directory in netrw without interfering with the original binding. However, I can't get `nmap <expr> ^ &ft ==# 'netrw' ? "\<Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir" : '^'` to call the right function. I've tested it, and `^` appears to be a no-op in a `.vimrc` consisting of just that line.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet what if you put `nmap ^ <Plug>...` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` ?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble After struggling with this a bit, I managed to call the right function using `nmap ^ :<c-u>call netrw#Call('NetrwBrowseUpDir', 1)<cr>` in the file `~/.vim/after/plugin/netrw.vim` . However, I can't seem to set up the arguments to `netrw#Call` correctly. I keep seeing a type error `E745: Using List as Number` somewhere inside `netrw#Call` .

Comment: @GregoryNisbet i haven’t looked at the code, but I’m wondering if `netrw#Call` just forwards it’s arguments and is expecting a list? But then perhaps two lists are being added later, only now one is a number, so things seem weird?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a global mapping and checking for the filetype in an expression, just set this mapping in a ftplugin for netrw and set it as a buffer-local mapping.

Create file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` with the following line:

```
nmap <buffer> ^ <Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir
```

**NOTE 1:** The [original mapping](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim#L6377) also uses `<silent>` and `<nowait>`, you might consider adding those yourself as well.

**NOTE 2:** Usually, when you add settings from a script in `ftplugin`, you also want to append a snippet to [the `b:undo_ftplugin` variable](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html?#undo_ftplugin) with commands to undo the effects of the script. In this case, that's probably not really necessary, since the `netrw` filetype is quite specific to `netrw` buffers and those don't really use `undo_ftplugin`.

**NOTE 3:** The code that sets up the mapping for `-` checks whether there's already a mapping for `<Plug>NetrwBrowseUpDir` and skips that mapping if one already exists. If you create your mapping from the `ftplugin`, your mapping will be created last, so the `-` command will continue to work on `netrw` buffers.